# Websockets convert byte[] to string

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, websocket, buffer

I have the following code:

```
            Console.WriteLine("New Socket connection opened");
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New message received : "+ Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
            }
```

When I send `Hello` my client, I can see `Hello?????????????` on the console. Clearly, it means I have a buffer of size `1024 * 4`, of which, the first few bytes are taken by `Hello`. How do I `trim` my String (eventually, I wanto pass JSON from my client to the server).

Comment: [.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocketreceiveresult.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebSockets_WebSocketReceiveResult_Count) ?

Comment: buffer.Count() and buffer.Length() both return 4096

Comment: Can you show the code that's sending the message?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.1 - all I am trying to do is Console.WriteLine() the message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) answered this

[WebSocketReceiveResult.Count Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocketreceiveresult.count?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Indicates the number of bytes that the WebSocket received.
>
> Count can be 0 in two cases:
>
> The WebSocket received an empty message. In this case the CloseStatus
>   property is None.
>
> The WebSocket received a close message from the remote endpoint. In
>   this case, the CloseStatus property is set to a value other than None.

[GetString(Byte[], Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_)

```
public virtual string GetString (byte[] bytes, int index, int count);
```

> When overridden in a derived class, decodes a sequence of bytes from
>   the specified byte array into a string.
>
> - bytes `Byte[]` The byte array containing the sequence of bytes to decode.
> - index `Int32` The index of the first byte to decode.
> - count `Int32` The number of bytes to decode.

So you will need something like this

```
Console.WriteLine("New message received : "+ Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,0,Result.Count));
```

However, and its a big however. There is more to go wrong, and i would seriously suggest getting a good `WebSocket` tutorial and some bullet proof (typical) designs